# How to display PDF from a byte64 string on my angular template in Angular6

Tags: angular6, angular-material-6, pdf-viewer

I am working on PDF view and download for my angular app, here i would want to download pdf on a section, but before that i want to display the pdf on my angular template, which i am stuck at, how could i accomplish this, kindly request assistance, thanks in advance.
This is the code i am using for download, how could i change this so i could even make it viewable on my UI.

```
onSubmitPolicyPDF() {
        let formValuePolicyPDF: any = {
            cst_policy_number: this.submitprop.data.policy_number,
        }
        this.policyService.policyPDF(formValuePolicyPDF)
            .pipe()
            .subscribe(poldownloaddata => {
                this.poldownloaddata = poldownloaddata,
                    console.log('poldownloaddata: ', poldownloaddata);
                console.log(atob(this.poldownloaddata.data.pdf_ccnt));
                const linkSource = 'data:application/pdf;base64,' + this.poldownloaddata.data.pdf_ccnt;
                // const linkSource = (atob(this.previewdata.data.pdf_ccnt));
                const downloadLink = document.createElement("a");
                const fileName = "policy.pdf";
                downloadLink.href = linkSource;
                downloadLink.download = fileName;
                downloadLink.click();
                (error: any) => this.errorMessage = <any>error
            }
            )
    }
```